# cannot call either didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken or didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError

Tags: swift, swift3, push-notification, devicetoken

My application **cannot call didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken on iOS10 devices, even the same code can call it on iOS11 devices**.

I don't know why it happening and how to solve this issue.

If anyone knows answers, please help me.

my environment is below:
Xcode: 9.2
Swift: 3.2
deployment target: 10.0

my code is below:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) {granted, error in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        if granted {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            })
        }
    }

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg) as String
    let tokenWithoutSpace = token.replacingOccurrences(of: "[ |<>]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
    print(tokenWithoutSpace)
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot call"?

Comment: it means function didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken() cannot be called.